# "It seems to me" vs "in my opinion"

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

On some pages, it is announced that "it seems to me..." is synonymous with "in my opinion", but I think  "it seems to me..." is less certain than "in my opinion". In the other word, I think that if I say " in my opinion, taking a course online is a better option to me" I am sure that "taking a course online is a better option to me", but if I say "it seems to me that taking a course is a better option to me", it implies that I am not sure about it.

Is the aforementioned note correct?

Comment: [Ways to Say **I THINK**](https://englishstudypage.com/speaking/ways-to-say-i-think/) include *In my opinion… I believe…
I assume… I would say…
In my point of view… I consider…
If you ask me… To me…
As far as I can tell… From my point of view…
To my mind… It is my view…
As far as I’m concerned… It’s my belief that…
The way I see things is that… I honestly believe that…
As I see it… To my way of thinking…
It seems to me that… I feel…*

Answer (score 4):

The two expressions are frequently interchangeable - and nobody would notice which of them you chose to use in your example. But some contexts are much better suited to one or the other.

For example, **in my opinion** works better when you are talking about issues, controversies, politics, religion and the like. In these instances, you are offering your view on these subjects. Hopefully, you have considered them sufficiently to form an educated view - an informed opinion.

**It seems to me** is better suited to appearances and particular circumstances.

> It seems to me that unless you employ a gardener, your garden will soon be overgrown.
> It seems to me that our son has been spending rather a lot of money lately.
> It seems to me that unless we eat the fruit soon, it will go off.
> It seems to me that unless we walk the dog regularly, it will put on weight.

And so on!